# What is the equivalent of ionic setDir function in angular 8?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, direction, angular8

What is the equivalent of ionic's `platform.setDir()` in angular 8 web application project ?

I am trying to change the direction of the whole app when the user changes the app's default language (including side menu, and toolbar).

Usually in Ionic I do it like the following:

`import { Platform } from`ionic-angular;`

and the change it using the function:

```
onlangChange()
{
    ...
    this.platform.setDir('rtl', true);
}
```

Comment: No such thing on angular.
if you wish to work with languages there are other ways to do it on angular.

Comment: @Talg123 can you propose a method or a link about it please

Comment: https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/simple-i18n-support-for-your-angular-apps-6138a47eb2a9